# Conversion of Array objects in javascript (nodejs+ mysql + sequelize)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

This is my json object:

```
   {
    excels:
       [ { field1: '123456789',
           field2: 'Mohamed',
           field3: 'Sameer'},

         { field1: '111111111',
           field2: 'Hameed',
           field3: 'Basha'},

         { field1: '222222222',
           field2: 'Mohamed',
           field3: 'Basha'} ],

      header:
       { '0': 'gsm',
         '1': 'firstName',
         '2': 'lastName'
    }

}
```

How to convert this into:

```
[{gsm:123456789;firstName:'Mohamed';lastName:'Sameer'},{gsm:111111111;firstName:'Hameed';lastName:'Basha'},{gsm:222222222;firstName:'Mohamed';lastName:'Basha'}]
```

is it possible to get this type of conversion?

Help me i am a newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let obj = {
excels:
   [ { field1: '123456789',
       field2: 'Mohamed',
       field3: 'Sameer'},

     { field1: '111111111',
       field2: 'Hameed',
       field3: 'Basha'},

     { field1: '222222222',
       field2: 'Mohamed',
       field3: 'Basha'} ],

  header:
   { '0': 'gsm',
     '1': 'firstName',
     '2': 'lastName',
     '3': 'street'} 
}

let targetObj = [];
let keysLength = Object.keys(obj["excels"][0]).length;
for(i=0;i< keysLength;i++) {
    targetObj[i] = {};
    let key = obj["header"][i]
    targetObj[i]['gsm'] = obj["excels"][i]["field1"];
    targetObj[i]['firstName'] = obj["excels"][i]["field2"];
    targetObj[i]['lastName'] = obj["excels"][i]["field3"];
}

console.log(targetObj)
```

Comment: ? if the json is dynamically changing like this {
excels:
   [ { field1: 'Mohamed',
       field2: '123456789',
       field3: 'Sameer'},

     { field1: 'Hameed',
       field2: '111111111',
       field3: 'Basha'},

     { field1: 'Mohamed',
       field2: '222222222',
       field3: 'Basha'} ],

  header:
   { '0': 'gsm',
     '1': 'firstName',
     '2': 'lastName',
     '3': 'street'} 
} . [{gsm:123456789;firstName:'Mohamed';lastName:'Sameer'},{gsm:111111111;firstName:'Hameed';lastName:'Basha'},{gsm:222222222;firstName:'Mohamed';lastName:'Basha'}]
 how to get?

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be much more clear to use `lodash.mapKeys` :

```
const mapKeys = require('lodash.mapkeys');

const arr = obj.excels.map(
  (excel) => {
    const keys = Object.values(obj.header)
    return mapKeys(excel, (value, key) => keys.shift())
  }
);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You need to install [lodash.mapkeys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.mapkeys) and to `const mapKeys = require('lodash.mapkeys')` (i've edited the snippet)